# clang-cl PCH missing header include error

Tags: c++, clang-cl

We generate our PCH as a preprocess step before compile time and then force include the PCH into every file in the project.  This works fine for us with MSVC cl but clang-cl is checking to see if the PCH is included in the sources (excluded by design).

I get the following error:

```
fatal error: #include of 'pch.hxx' not seen while attempting to use precompiled header
```

Shouldn't clang-cl detect the /FI (or /clang:-include) as a header within the source?

Comment: check where does your preprocessor generate `pch.hxx` and then ensure the the path is included in compilation step

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have verified that all path information is correct.  I removed the absolute path information generated by cmake from the description to make the post clearer.  The PCH generater we are using is [cotire](https://github.com/sakra/cotire) a very simply library.

Answer (score 0):

clang-cl should (and does) treat `/FI` arguments as include lines. Can you paste the compile command that's failing? Maybe you're passing slightly different paths to `/Yu` and `/Fi`?